# signOut of user in Flutter using Firebase authentication is not working

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I followed this tutorial-series on Youtube step by step ([videolink](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3sY3RWciNw&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9j--TKIdkb3ISfRbJeJYQwC&index=9)) and already searched for similar questions but my code just isn't working.

I already made sure that everything is async & watched the tutorial more than twice but I can't find the problem source. Also, logging in and registering is working fine.

What am I doing wrong here? Here's my code:

main.dart:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp( MyApp());
}
...
return StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(
    value: AuthService().user,
    child: MaterialApp(
     ...
```

userModel.dart:

```
class UserModel {

  String uid;
  String displayName;
  String avatarUrl;

  UserModel(this.uid, {this.displayName, this.avatarUrl});
}
```

auth.dart:

```
class AuthService {

  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  //create user obj based on User from Firebase
  UserModel _currentUser(User user) {
    return user != null ? UserModel(user.uid) : null;
  }

  //auth change user stream
  Stream<UserModel> get user {
    return _auth.authStateChanges()
      .map(_currentUser);
  }

  ...

  //log out
  Future signOut() async{
    try {
      return await _auth.signOut();
    } catch(e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

page with the logout call:

```
class Settings extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _SettingsState createState() => _SettingsState();
}

class _SettingsState extends State<Settings> {

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  ...
  onPressed: () {
    _showLogoutDialog(context, isRegistered, _auth);
  },
  ...
  showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(30.0))
    ),
    backgroundColor: overlayDarkRightBottom,
    title: Text('Log out?'),
    content: Text('All non synchronized data will be lost.',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, letterSpacing: 1)),
    actions: [
      FlatButton(
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.8,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Icon(Icons.logout, color: Colors.red),
            SizedBox(width: 10.0),
            Text('Log out',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, color: Colors.red)),
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () async {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          await _auth.signOut();
        },
       )
     ],
    )
  )
```

**UPDATE**: the logout seems to work fine (when I hot restart the app I get to the login screen again), but how come that the user state doesn't change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sorry, everything did work fine, I just had to pop a Page laying above everything. I'll leave this question in case somebody does the same mistake.

```
Navigator.of(context).pop();
```